# What's the fastest way to query multiple tables at once where each table represents one year of data?

Tags: mysql, index, join, view

I'm developing an web app based around a database with multiple decades of data with multiple schema changes over the years. Each year of data is released as a zip file containing CSVs named `table1.csv`, `table2.csv`, `table3.csv`, etc.

My initial goal was to just get the data into an *intermediate* MySQL database without making any significant changes. Since there are schema changes over the years, I couldn't get away with simply creating the `table1`, `table2`, `table3` tables so my compromise was to add a year prefix. For example, `1990_table1`, `1991_table1`, `1992_table1` etc. Besides this, I added some basic indexes on columns that can uniquely identify a record which I'll get into next.

One of the complications with the schema is that there's no single primary key. `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5` as well as three date columns `date_month`, `date_day`, and `date_year` comprise the unique identifier in the early years. In the middle years, the three date columns are combined into one `date` column with varying formats such as `mddyy` and later, `mddyyyy`. In recent years, data has been released with a primary key that combines all of the `columnX` columns and `date` column, for example: `column1_column2_column3_column4_column5_date`.

To normalize the date formats, I created a separate table that has a standard `date` column with columns that tie back to the original tables. Then I imported the data for each year with using a few functions to parse the varying date formats. Now, to get a standard date for each record, I'd run:

```sql
-- Early years.
SELECT
    `1990_table1`.*,
    `date_table`.`normalized_date`
FROM `1990_table1`
INNER JOIN
    `date_table`
ON
    `1990_table1`.`column1` = `date_table`.`column1` AND
    `1990_table1`.`column2` = `date_table`.`column2` AND
    `1990_table1`.`column3` = `date_table`.`column3` AND
    `1990_table1`.`column4` = `date_table`.`column4` AND
    `1990_table1`.`column5` = `date_table`.`column5` AND
    `1990_table1`.`month`   = `date_table`.`month`   AND
    `1990_table1`.`day`     = `date_table`.`day`     AND
    `1990_table1`.`year`    = `date_table`.`year`;

-- Middle years.
SELECT
    `2000_table1`.*,
    `date_table`.`date`
FROM `2000_table1`
INNER JOIN
    `date_table`
ON
    `2000_table1`.`column1` = `date_table`.`column1` AND
    `2000_table1`.`column2` = `date_table`.`column2` AND
    `2000_table1`.`column3` = `date_table`.`column3` AND
    `2000_table1`.`column4` = `date_table`.`column4` AND
    `2000_table1`.`column5` = `date_table`.`column5` AND
    `2000_table1`.`date`    = `date_table`.`date`;

-- Recent years.
SELECT
    `2020_table1`.*,
    `date_table`.`date`
FROM `2020_table1`
INNER JOIN
    `date_table`
ON
    `2020_table1`.`combined_identifier` = `date_table`.`combined_identifier`;
```

My next step was creating views for each year using the `JOIN`s above. In addition to getting a standard date, there are two more joins pulling in data from `1-to-1` tables. These tables relate back to the original table, again, based on the `columnX` and `date` columns.

After that, I created another view for testing purposes that `UNION ALL`s all the years with the same schema. So for example, 1990-1999. My ultimate goal is to create a "master" view that allows me to query all the years at once, but for testing purposes it's 1990-1999 currently:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `1990_to_1999_table1_view` WHERE YEAR(`date`) = '1990' AND `ZIP` = '90210' LIMIT 100;
```

The problem is that this query is unacceptably slow to be used in an autosuggest search field in my web app. I'm not quite sure why this query is so slow (single digit seconds). Ideally, I'd like to get it under 250ms.

Here's what `EXPLAIN` shows. `Nested loop inner join` is repeated and looks more-or-less the same for each year in the view that `UNION`s all the years together. I cut off the other `Nested loop inner join`s for brevity.

```
-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=232.39..232.39 rows=0.1)
    -> Table scan on my_view  (cost=232.39..232.39 rows=0.1)
        -> Union all materialize  (cost=229.89..229.89 rows=0.1)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1.12 rows=0.0007)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=0.86 rows=0.01)
                    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=0.79 rows=0.1)
                        -> Index lookup on 1990_table1 using ZIP_INDEX (ZIP='90210')  (cost=0.35 rows=1)
                        -> Filter: (1990_table2.column1 = 1990_table1.column1)  (cost=0.32 rows=0.1)
                            -> Index lookup on 1990_table2 using column2_INDEX (column2=1990_table1.column2)  (cost=0.32 rows=1)
                    -> Filter: (1990_table1.column1 = 1990_table1.column1)  (cost=0.61 rows=0.1)
                        -> Index lookup on 1990_table1 using COMBINED_IDENTIFIER_KEY_INDEX (column2=1990_table1.column2, column3=1990_table1.column3, column4=1990_table1.column4)  (cost=0.61 rows=1)
                -> Filter: ((date_table.year = 1990_table1.year) and (date_table.day = 1990_table1.day) and (date_table.month = 1990_table1.month) and (date_table.column2 = 1990_table1.column2) and (date_table.column1 = 1990_table1.column1) and (date_table.date = 1990_table1.date) and (1990_table1.column4 = date_table.column4) and (year(date_table.`DATE`) = 1990))  (cost=17.77 rows=0.05)
                    -> Index lookup on date_table using column3_index (column3=1990_table1.column3), with index condition: (1990_table1.column3 = date_table.column3)  (cost=17.77 rows=19)
```

Is it a bad idea to create a main view (`table1_view`) of sub-views (`1990_to_1999_table1_view`, `2000_to_2009_table1_view`, etc.) of sub-sub-views (`1990_table1_view`, `1991_table1_view`, etc.)? Or can I improve the queries with different joins or indexes? Or should I bite the bullet and create brand new tables (all-in-all about 100gb) with a unified schema that all the year-prefixed tables can be imported to?

Comment: Adding the current table and index definitions to your Post would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong approach.  Do this instead:

1. Load each CSV file into its own table.
2. If there is no date or datetime column in the tables, add one.
3. Combine the tables into a single table.  (And toss the tables from step 1.)  For each table: `INSERT ... SELECT ...`
4. Write queries to use that one table.  When needed, include a date range in the `WHERE` clause.

If you will be purging old years, we can talk about Partitioning, otherwise, that technique is unlikely to benefit you.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, using `VIEW`s with underlying `SELECT ... UNION ALL`s is too inefficient to achieve my goal of being able to query all the data at once. Let's say for example, that `1990_table1`, `1991_table1`, etc. all had the same schema and indexes. If I `SELECT` each year table and `UNION ALL` the following year tables, would it be slow because all the indexes are broken up? Is having one singular index the key factor in performance here?

Comment: @Tyler - Well, it is a question of breaking up the table versus breaking up the INDEX.  And, yes, `VIEWs` are "syntactic sugar" and seldom if ever help with performance; they sometimes _hurt_ performance.  My 20+ years of experience with MySQL let me to bluntly lead with "wrong approach".  When we get into the specific queries, I can help "count the disk hits", which is the main metric for performance.

Comment: And, anyway, having a single table will make _your_ coding so much simpler.